# Literature on Private Countries

Tags: reference-request, political-economy, austrian

Amidst Anarchocapitalist authors such as Murray Rothbard, are there any who discuss the possibility of privately-owned countries, with their own set of private laws, police services and courts?

Comment: This question seems like it might get better replies at [politics.SE].

Comment: You might want to look up "Freetown Christiania" and "liberland".

Comment: Economical wise, any syndicate or entities that bought over(bribe) institution will fit the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Murray Rothbard gave a "natural rights" justification for an AnCap society.

David Friedman (son of Milton Friedman) discusses and gives a *consequentialist* defence for an Anarcho-Capitalist society. It's discussed in his book 'The Machinery of Freedom' and references 14th century Iceland for an approximation of how a society based on private laws and courts work.

Murray Rothbard, however, is still is the best known AnCap theoretician.